# Rails scoped association w/ nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following classes:

```
class Business < AR::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :owned_locations, -> { owned }, class_name: 'Location'
  has_many :good_locations, -> { good }, class_name: 'Location'
  has_many :bad_locations, -> { bad }, class_name: 'Location'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owned_locations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :good_locations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bad_locations, allow_destroy: true
end

class Location < AR::Base
  belongs_to :business
  scope :owned, -> { where(type: 'owned') }
  scope :good, -> { where(type: 'good') }
  scope :bad, -> { where(type: 'bad') }
end
```

Basically I'm trying to set up an association where `locations` can be assigned to multiple buckets (types) but all be stored in the same table.  I'm running into an issue with a nested form:

```
= simple_form_for @business do |f|
  = f.fields_for :owned_locations, @business.owned_locations do |lf|
    # location fields
```

My controller has the appropriate permitted params:

```
params.permit(
  :business => [
    :name,
    :owned_locations_attributes => [
      # locations_attributes
    ]
  ]
)
```

I'm not getting any unpermitted params errors, so I'm confident I have that all set up correctly.  But the locations are not getting assigned to the business.  These are the errors:

```
{
  :"owned_locations.business"=>["can't be blank"], 
  :"good_locations.business"=>["can't be blank"], 
  :"bad_locations.business"=>["can't be blank"]
}
```

I don't know enough about the inner-workings of the Rails API to debug this.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use simple_fields_for when you're creating a nested form with simple_form.

```
= simple_form_for @business do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :owned_locations, @business.owned_locations do |lf|
        # location fields
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  If it were, wouldn't I have an issue rendering the form or get an unpermitted params error?